# How to write the XSLT for xml source

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to display the trailer record as `Current Date| Max (wd:periodend) | Count(no.of rows)` using XSLT from XML source. I am getting the output data correctly for `CurrentDate` and `Count(no.of rows)` but not for `Max(wd:periodend)`.

I am new to XSLT.

Here is the XML:

```xml
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT206">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:ssn>123456789</wd:ssn>
        <wd:lastname>Michale</wd:lastname>
        <wd:firstname>Kaffe</wd:firstname>
        <wd:originalhiredate>11/02/2015</wd:originalhiredate>
        <wd:zip>75063</wd:zip>
        <wd:dob>05/24/1983</wd:dob>
        <wd:ethinicity>4</wd:ethinicity>
        <wd:status>Active</wd:status>
        <wd:periodend>02/26/2022</wd:periodend>
        <wd:periodenddate>2022-02-26</wd:periodenddate>
        <wd:fuitaxwagesytd>7000</wd:fuitaxwagesytd>
        <wd:fuitaxwages>0</wd:fuitaxwages>
        <wd:ftwytd>36523.37</wd:ftwytd>
        <wd:ftw>4714.27</wd:ftw>
        <wd:fgwytd>41382.3</wd:fgwytd>
        <wd:fgw>5436.46</wd:fgw>
        <wd:statetaxablewagesytd>0</wd:statetaxablewagesytd>
        <wd:statetaxablewages>0</wd:statetaxablewages>
        <wd:statewithholdingytd>0</wd:statewithholdingytd>
        <wd:statewithholding>0</wd:statewithholding>
        <wd:overtimeamountytd>0</wd:overtimeamountytd>
       
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:ssn>987654321</wd:ssn>
        <wd:lastname>Wi</wd:lastname>
        <wd:firstname>Marcy</wd:firstname>
        <wd:originalhiredate>03/21/2016</wd:originalhiredate> 
        <wd:zip>92660</wd:zip>
        <wd:dob>01/19/1955</wd:dob>
        <wd:ethinicity>1</wd:ethinicity>
        <wd:status>Active</wd:status>
        <wd:periodend>03/13/2022</wd:periodend>
        <wd:periodenddate>2022-03-13</wd:periodenddate>
        <wd:fuitaxwagesytd>7000</wd:fuitaxwagesytd>
        <wd:fuitaxwages>0</wd:fuitaxwages>
        <wd:ftwytd>71698.56</wd:ftwytd>
        <wd:ftw>20025.94</wd:ftw>
        <wd:fgwytd>77916.44</wd:fgwytd>
        <wd:fgw>21483.07</wd:fgw>
        <wd:statetaxablewagesytd>71698.56</wd:statetaxablewagesytd>
        <wd:statetaxablewages>20025.94</wd:statetaxablewages>
        <wd:statewithholdingytd>5972.01</wd:statewithholdingytd>
        <wd:statewithholding>1776.1</wd:statewithholding>
        <wd:overtimeamountytd>2737.9</wd:overtimeamountytd>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

This is how I have written in xslt but not working for Max:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT206">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xd;&#xa;'"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vDateFormat" select="'[M01][D01][Y0001]'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDateTimeFormat" select="'[D01]-[MN,*-3]-[Y0001]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]'"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <!--declare root variables here such as current datetime or other repeating values-->
        
        <!--Create the header record-->
        <xsl:call-template name="header"/>
        
        <!--Create the trailer record-->
        <xsl:call-template name="detail"/> 
        
        <!--Create the trailer record-->
        <xsl:call-template name="trailer"/> 
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--Header Template-->
    <xsl:template name="header">
        
        <xsl:text>Corp Code|Social Security Number (SSN)|Last Name|First Name|Original Start Work Date|Most Recent Rehire Date|Most Recent Termination Date|Most Recent Termination Reason|Home Address 1|Home Address 2|Home City|Home State|Home Zip Code|Birth Date|Ethnicity Code|Employee ID|Employment Status|Payroll Frequency|Job Title|Exempt Indicator|Pay Rate|FT/PT Status|Legal Entity Name|FEIN|Location Code|PPSD|PPED|YTD Uncapped Gross FUTA Wages|Period Uncapped Gross FUTA Wages|YTD Federal Taxable Wages|Period Federal Taxable Wages|YTD Federal Gross Wages|Period Federal Gross Wages|YTD State Taxable Wages|Period State Taxable Wages|YTD State Withholding|Period State Withholding|State Abbreviation for State to which Withholding is paid|YTD Overtime Wages|Period Overtime Wages|YTD All Hours Paid|Period All Hours Paid|YTD Regular Hours|Period Regular Hours|YTD Overtime Hours|Period Overtime Hours|Vendor Reference ID</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    
    <xsl:template name="detail">
        
        
        <xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
            <Record>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:corpcode"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>      
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:ssn"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:lastname"/>    
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:firstname"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <!--
                <originalhiredate>
                    <xsl:call-template name="stripTimeFromDate">
                        <xsl:with-param name="subjectDate" select="wd:originalhiredate" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </originalhiredate> -->
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:originalhiredate"/>
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:rehiredate"/>              
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:terminationdate"/>                     
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:termreason"/> 
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>                  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:addressline1"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:addressline2"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>      
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:city"/>    
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:state"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:zip"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:dob"/>                 
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:ethinicity"/>      
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:empid"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:status"/>              
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:frequency"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>      
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:title"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:exempt"/>          
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:payrate"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>              
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:timetype"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:entity"/>          
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:fein"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>                  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:loccode"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>      
                
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:periodstart"/>             
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:periodend"/>                   
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>              
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:fuitaxwagesytd"/>          
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:fuitaxwages"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:ftwytd"/>          
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:ftw"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:fgwytd"/>          
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>              
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:fgw"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:statetaxablewagesytd"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:statetaxablewages"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                
                
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:statewithholdingytd"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:statewithholding"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker/wd:statewithholding"/>          
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:overtimeamountytd"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>              
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:overtimeamount"/>          
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:allhoursytd"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:allhours"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>                  
                
                
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:regularhoursytd"/>         
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:regularhours"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:overtimehoursytd"/>        
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>              
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:overtimehours"/>       
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
                
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:refid"/>       
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="trailer">
        <Trailer>
            
            
            
            <Name>Gorla, Sandeep</Name>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
         <!--   <xsl:value-of select="max(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:periodenddate/xs:date(.))"/>-->    
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>     
            <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry)"/>          
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        </Trailer>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I used dummy data @Parfait so we should be good.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a minor adjustment.

Uncomment max date counting line and use `xsd:date(.)` prefix:

```
<xsl:value-of select="max(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:periodenddate/xsd:date(.))"/>
```

Also, XSLT 2.0 `string-join()` function could be handy to concatenate data elements for each row with the vertical bar "|". It will simplify the XSLT significantly.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">
            <!--<Record>-->
                <xsl:value-of select="string-join((wd:corpcode,
                    wd:ssn,
                    wd:lastname,
                    wd:firstname,
                    wd:originalhiredate,
                    wd:rehiredate,
                    wd:terminationdate,
                    wd:termreason,
                    wd:addressline1,
                    wd:addressline2,
                    ...), '|')"/>

            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    <!--</Record>-->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Because you are after textual output, I commented out `<Record>` tags

**Modified trailer template**

```
<xsl:template name="trailer">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-join(('Gorla, Sandeep',
            string(max(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:periodenddate/xsd:date(.))),
            string(count(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry))), '|')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Gives the following output:

```
Gorla, Sandeep|2022-03-13|2
```

Comment: You could simplify it even further by adding a `separator` attribute to the `xsl:value-of` instruction. Then you won't need the `string-join()` function.

Comment: @michael.hor257k , I wrote like this but not getting the max periodenddate in trailer record:        <Trailer>
            
            
            
            <Name>Gorla, Sandeep</Name>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text> 
   
            <xsl:value-of select="count(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry)"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>  
            <xsl:value-of select="max(wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:periodenddate/xsd:date(.))"/>    

            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        </Trailer>